# Modeling Airplane Nose Shape

Tags: modeling

I need help recreating the nose shape of the airplane you see in the images below. I also have the .blend file included because I think it would be easier to see everything that I have already tried and so you can see the shape that I'm trying to go for.

http://pasteall.org/blend/index.php?id=53057

Please look through the different layers in the .blend file. The second layer has an airplane that was downloaded online for reference which I'm trying to recreate, and the rest of the layers are just attempts. I have tried using the bridge operation mostly and the loop tools addon to create the circle at the end. The third layer is my mesh but merged with the front of the other airplane. I also had to apply one subdivision so I had more vertices to work with. Also, the name of the airplane is SR22T if you may need more reference images.

[image: Text]
<sub>(source: [discordapp.net](https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/185590907947581440/688851898010173454/Screenshot_92.jpg))</sub>

[image: Text]
[image: Text]

Comment: Not to be nosy  ... Can you point out specifically what you think is deficient in words and diagram?  Perhaps a close up of the nose  of your work would help .  I am aware that you included a file.

Comment: [link](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/536037068149882884/688877154557100045/Nose.png) The outline you see is separating the mesh I already have and the nose from the other model

Comment: Also, I found this timelapse of someone modeling a similar airplane but I couldn't find the first part https://youtu.be/3pV3j7QPbAk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image] I fixed it by using creases and looptools for the end bits